# I get Auth::user is null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I create middleware for an admin role using the following code:

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware
```

After that, I create a route for the login page:

```
Route::get('admin/login', ['middleware'=>'web','as'=>'admin.login','uses'=>'AdminController@loginView']);
Route::post('admin/login',['middleware'=>'web','as'=>'admin.login','uses'=>'AdminController@login']);
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware' => ['auth.admin','web']],     function()
{
    Route::get('/', ['as'=>'admin.home','uses'=>'AdminController@index']);
    Route::get('/home',    ['as'=>'admin.home','uses'=>'AdminController@index']);
});
```

And the controller is

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    //
    function index(){
        return 'welcome';
    }

    function loginView(){
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    function login(Request $request){
        $error = $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:5',
        ]);
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');
        $remember = $request->input('remember');

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password,'type'=>'admin'], $remember)) {

            // Authentication passed...
            Auth::login(Auth::user(), $remember);
            return redirect()->route('admin.home');
        }
        else{//('message', 'Login Failed')
            return redirect()->route('admin.login')->withErrors($request->all(), "message")->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

And in AdminMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    var_dump(Auth::user());
    if(!Auth::check()){
        return redirect()->route('admin.login')->withErrors('You are not logged in');
    }
    elseif ($request->user()->type != 'admin'){
        dd($request->user());
        return redirect()->route('admin.login')->withErrors('You have not authority');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

The error is: I always get null for each $request->user() or Auth:user in AdminMiddleware.

Comment: Do you create a migration?

Comment: yes i have create and run migration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the middleware to the route group in an incorrect order.

Right now you have this order `['auth.admin', 'web']` which means that the `auth.admin` middleware will be executed before the middleware from the `web` group, and since `web` contains the `StartSession` middleware, you won't have any session in `auth.admin` which is needed to get the authenticated user.

So simply switch the middleware order like so:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware' => ['web', 'auth.admin']], function () {
    // now the session is set up in `web` and then you have it in `auth.admin`
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case the actual problem was a blank line before the PHP starting tag.

I used following core PHP function to redirect instead of returning a view file from controller or instead of using Laravel redirect.

```
header('Location: /');
```

It printed the actual file which had a blank line. Removing this line fixed my problem.

There were thousands of files in my code base. My assumption was that I had tried different scripts to find such blank lines at start of any file and there was no such file as per those scripts results. I assumed there was no blank line in any of my files. But header('Location: /') proved that my assumption was not wrong, and I was working on the wrong lines.